# Jquery iCheck Not Work in list input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I work with Jquery [iCheck](http://damirfoy.com/iCheck) plugin. I add `iradio_minimal` `class` For change `checkbox/radiobox` to new style and Set function for change all `input`, But this not worked. I think my`jquery` `function` not work in action.

how to fix this?

Jquery function:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
        radioClass: 'iradio_minimal',
        increaseArea: '20%'
      });
    });
```

HTML:

```
              <ul class="list">
                <li>
                  <input tabindex="5" type="checkbox" id="minimal-checkbox-1">
                  <label for="minimal-checkbox-1">Checkbox 1</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input tabindex="6" type="checkbox" id="minimal-checkbox-2" checked>
                  <label for="minimal-checkbox-2">Checkbox 2</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="minimal-checkbox-disabled" disabled>
                  <label for="minimal-checkbox-disabled">Disabled</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="minimal-checkbox-disabled-checked" checked disabled>
                  <label for="minimal-checkbox-disabled-checked">Disabled &amp; checked</label>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

Live Demo in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVSEB/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dVSEB/4/

```
$('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal',
    increaseArea: '20%'
});
```

I got it working (just about) by including the iCheck code in the actual JSFiddle itself

The problem was that the iCheck function was not recognized, which is typically a sign that the file is not being loaded properly. **How are you calling the iCheck file?**